# check sql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There's a mysql command line it should print `TXT` row when `STATUS` row is `2000` in another table with the same `ID` = 1 , its like connecting to another table;

First table (`tb_users`):

```
 ID | TXT
 ----------
 1  | 9
```

Second table (`tb_check`):

```
 ID | STATUS
 ----------
 1  | 2000
```

my mysql command line:

```
 SELECT * FROM `tb_users` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is `ORDER BY ORDER BY` ??

Comment: @Saty a typo ... corrected.

Comment: Very nice.  Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: It can be easily achieved by joining, You have not tried yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query should be something like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_users TU 
    JOIN tb_check TC ON TU.id=TC.id 
WHERE TC.STATUS=2000;
```

You've use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) in order to get the result from connecting tables. By connecting tables I mean We need to use [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Why? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: please add `ORDER BY RAND()`  too;

Comment: This is absolute nit-picking on my part, but here it goes. Whenever possible don't use `RAND()` when it comes to queries. It's O(n) type and can significantly slow down the query itself.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's true. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

SELECT * FROM tb_users TU, tb_check TC WHERE TU.ID=TC.ID AND TC.status=2000 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;